# SQLITE delete method in Java

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have a method that should delete a Person(a row) from my database. 
I am getting the error message that I created in the catch. I just started working with Databases and I have mostly been piecing together different techniques. I'm not sure what to do

public static void deletePerson(String firstNameOfPersonToDelete, String lastNameOfPersonToDelete) {
        Statement stmt = null;

```
    try {
        // Create database connection
        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:PERSON.db");

        // Create Statement object
        stmt = c.createStatement();

        // Get person we're about to delete
        String getPersonQuery = "SELECT SSN FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, AGE, CREDITCARD FROM PERSON WHERE FIRSTNAME = '"
                + firstNameOfPersonToDelete + "' AND LASTNAME = '" + lastNameOfPersonToDelete + "'";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(getPersonQuery);

        String ssn = rs.getString("SSN");
        String firstName = rs.getString("FIRSTNAME");
        String lastName = rs.getString("LASTNAME");
        String age = rs.getString("AGE");
        String creditCard = rs.getString("CREDITCARD");

        String deletePersonStatement = "DELETE FROM PERSON WHERE FIRSTNAME = '" + firstName + "' AND LASTNAME = '"
                + lastName + "'";

        stmt.executeUpdate(deletePersonStatement);

        System.out.println("The following record was deleted:\n" + ssn + "\n" + firstName + " " + lastName + "\n"
                + age + "\n" + creditCard);
        System.out.println("\nThe database contains the following records: ");

        ArrayList<Object> myPeople = findAllPeople();

        for (Object element : myPeople) {
            System.out.println(element.toString());
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err); 
        System.out.println("Error: The person: \"" + firstNameOfPersonToDelete + " " + lastNameOfPersonToDelete
                + "\" was not found. No records were deleted.");
        System.out.println("\nThe database contains the following records: ");
        ArrayList<Object> myPeople = findAllPeople();

        for (Object element : myPeople) {
            System.out.println(element.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

> java.sql.SQLException: no such column: 'SSN'Error: The person: "Fitzgerald Grant" was not found. No records were deleted.
>     at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.findColumn(JDBC3ResultSet.java:48)
>     at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getString(JDBC3ResultSet.java:443)
>     at Test.deletePerson(Test.java:181)
>     at Test.main(Test.java:65)

Comment: When asking for debugging help it is important to include the actual stack trace. Add `e.printStackTrace(System.err);` to your `catch` block and then [edit] your question to show what it says.

Comment: Also, read up on `PreparedStatement`, "parameterized queries", and "SQL injection".

Comment: This is not a forum; don't change the question to something different after is has been answered. If you have a different question, ask a new one.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT SSN FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, AGE, CREDITCARD FROM ...
          ^
```

This is the same as `SSN AS FIRSTNAME`, i.e., in the output of the query, the `SSN` column is renamed to `FIRSTNAME`. You apparently forgot a comma.

In any case, you got this error because there is no `SSN` column.
You have to ensure that you create this table with this column, or if you have an old database, that you add this column.

Comment: wow. so I added the comma, and now i get a different error: the database file is locked

Comment: There is a column `SSN` (otherwise a different error would have been produced on execute instead), it just has been aliased as `FIRSTNAME`, which means that `getString("SSN")` will result in an error as their is no column in the result set called `SSN` (result set columns are accessed by index or by alias, not by original column name).